# Div height HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I need a little help here for my html/css code ... I need to follow the height of my divbody to divwrapper, since the divwrapper was floated to left, the height of my divbody is only 10 (theres padding valued 5px). This is the code, thanks!

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Information Technology</title>
</head>
<style>

    body{
        margin:0px;
    }

    .divbody{
        width:970px;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#cecece;
        margin:0px auto;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .divwrapper{
        height:auto;
        background-color:#eee;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .divcontent{
        width:480px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:yellow;
        float:left;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <div class="divbody">

        <div class="divwrapper">

            <div class="divcontent">

            </div>

            <div class="divcontent">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please make clear you question, its not easily understood. What exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use clearfix method to fix your float issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="divbody clearfix">

    <div class="divwrapper">

        <div class="divcontent">

        </div>

        <div class="divcontent">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
        margin:0px;
    }

    .divbody{
        width:970px;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#cecece;
        margin:0px auto;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .divwrapper{
        height:auto;
        background-color:#eee;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .divcontent{
        width:480px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:yellow;
        float:left;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }

.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/F4Hfj/)
[Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) you can find more information about clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `position: absolute;` to `divbody`

```
.divbody{
        position: absolute;
        width:970px;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#cecece;
        margin:0px auto;
        padding:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` (which is one among many other potential options) to your `.divbody` to construct a new block context.

Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

Read more at: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h44pZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `overflow:auto;` to `divbody` class. What this does is that it wraps itself up according to its child elements.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8tj/)**

**The Code:**

```
.divbody{
        width:970px;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#cecece;
        margin:0px auto;
        padding:5px;
        overflow:auto; /* The needs to be added */  
    }
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` as quick fix, we are now moving to new age modern browsers, say good bye to cleat:both or clearfix:after